# In react-navigation, how do I change the color of the overlay visible when performing a back gesture?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Using a `StackNavigator` from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org), when performing the back gesture (swiping the top card from left to right to pop it off the stack) there is a bright white overlay that appears on the card below.  How do I change the color of that overlay or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create your own `Transitioner`. Essentially create an Animated View that wraps your scene and adjust the opacity. See the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner) with more info and examples.